# DocuSign Integration in On-Premise File System

Tags: docusignapi

We have an on-premise file system software that is run by different Clients on different instances/network with different URLS, for example: -

Client1 will have URL https://docs.company1.com running on Company1's web server 
Client2 will have URL https://files.company2.com running on Company2's web server

Each client will have their own customers which is not known to to us.

We want to integrate docusign API so customers from each Client can digitally sign files from their on-premise instance.

### Questions:-

1. Once we integrate our product and docusign with an integrator key and get it certified to go-live by docusign, we want all our clients and their customers to be able to use the integration without the clients having to go through separate certification again. Is this possible? If so, are each Clients going to share the common integration key?
2. We want each Client to pay for their own API pricing as given here https://www.docusign.com/products-and-pricing/api-plans-b  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes to both. Once your integrator key is live in the production environment, it can be used on any account. Your clients will be able to purchase and manage their own DocuSign accounts, so that they hold their own envelopes.

You will want to package the integrator key in your application so that your clients do not need to go through certification. You'll want to keep the key hidden so that users of your application can't 'steal' your key and use it themselves.

Comment: Thanks Drew. So based on your answer, I see that the clients having a different URL does not matter here at all. We are yet to support OAUTH authentication in our application. Can we accomplish this integration without using OAUTH?